# How to disable openfaces validation?

Tags: validation, jsf, openfaces

The application I'm working on uses an openfaces component to display a tree in our web app.
So far, so good.

Unfortunatly, it seems openfaces try to install itself everywhere in application.

As a consequence, this leads to unwanted calls being done to openfaces validation backend. That's what I discovered when, doing profiling, I saw we spent a certain amount of time doing String.equals checks on a page that is virtually full of select JSF widgets :

[image: 1 million calls to String#equals ? That's what I call too MUCH]

Which leads me to the initial question : as this seems to be initiated by some validation component of openfaces, component which is declared in openfaces faces-config.xml file :

```
  <lifecycle>
    <phase-listener>org.openfaces.component.validation.RenderKitReplacerPhaseListener</phase-listener>
  </lifecycle>
  <lifecycle>
    <phase-listener>org.openfaces.component.validation.ValidatorPhaseListener</phase-listener>
  </lifecycle>
```

How can I disable openfaces validation, at least for that page ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenFaces have aplication context parameter.
You can learn more here:http://openfaces.org/documentation/developersGuide/installation-and-configuration.html